# Is this natural expression "These all tasks are attracting ~"

Tags: expressions

Is this natural expression?

"These all tasks are attracting to me"

Comment: What is your meaning in this sentence.  I just realized when Jacob posted his answer that the giant response I'm writing might be for the wrong meaning entirely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this has a number of problems as written.

I understand your intent with this sentence to mean:

> I am being assigned many tasks.

With the idea that it is a sudden increase in quantity, and that I have been singled out for the tasks.

1.
The placement of the word **all** is off.  You might try reading the answer to [Meaning and the position of “all” in a sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29551/meaning-and-the-position-of-all-in-a-sentence) for some other examples of it in a sentence and the changes it invokes as its place is moved through a sentence.  It's an incredibly flexible word; you could use it in any position in your sentence except for where you've placed it or preceding *me*, with varying meaning.  The two places where it fits most naturally with the meaning that I'm working from would be:

> **All of** these ... OR ... are **all** ...

(I'm avoiding including more of the sentence at this point because I don't want to use words that I wouldn't naturally.)

2.
The verb **attracting** does not work here.  Attract is used in a few senses:

- objects experiencing a force that pulls them together
- humans feeling romantically pulled together
- animals (including humans) being pulled toward something (food, a mate, etc) by a signal (a scent, flower color, etc)

There are surely other ways to use the word figuratively, but unless your sentence is going to include a simile comparing yourself to a magnet it's probably not the right choice.  Instead, I would say something like:

> ... are being assigned to me.
>   ... are being given to me.
>   ... are coming my way.
>   ... keep popping up.

and I would choose among them based on the source of the assignments.  That is, if I were being told to do them by my boss, I would use the first or second, the third is somewhat uncertain in source, and the fourth implies a variety of sources for the tasks.

3.
The word **tasks** is an unlikely choice.  It's not an uncommon word, exactly, but synonyms like *jobs* or *assignments* or *chores* would be much more likely.  I can't see myself saying the word *tasks* in this sort of sentence in very many circumstances at all.

The way I would say the sentence, **if** I understand its meaning, would be:

> All of this work is being given to me.
>   All of these projects have been assigned to me.
>   All of these jobs keep coming my way.

If instead you meant **attractive** instead of **attracting** then the sentence meaning changes entirely.  A fair bit of what I wrote still works (points 1 and 3 in particular) but point 2 will need some editing.

Answer (score 0):

No, in fact that sounds quite unnatural. You would say "all of these tasks are attractive to me." I doubt many people would say this though. "All of these tasks seem good to me" or "I like all of these tasks" would probably be more common.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's totally unnatural to the point where an English speaker would have great difficulty in understanding you at all.
You could say "I find these tasks attractive" it's unusual, but could be said.
You could also say " I seem to attract many tasks" but again it's very unusual.

Better examples:
I am attracted to these tasks because they are fairly easy.
I do not know why I am attracting so many of these tasks.
 
It's not an attractive task.

Hope this helps.